# How do I add a background image when opening the page on the slider that I have created?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a slider which when clicked will change the background. At the beginning of opening the page the background is white. How do I add a background image at the beginning of the page?

I want the first page to have a background image. If one of the features is clicked the background image will change:

[image: Page when first loaded]

[image: After the first click]

after clicking the icon, the image that should have been replaced is not replaced, because I want the first time I open this page there is a background image and after clicking the icon the background image is replaced.

[image]

```js
$('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 6,
  speed: 300,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  variableHeight: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: false,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});

$(document).on('click', '.sg-feature', function() {
  $('.sg-feature-desc').addClass('hidden');
  $(this).find('div').removeClass('hidden');
});

let gambar1 = document.querySelector('#gambar1');
let gambar2 = document.querySelector('#gambar2');
let gambar3 = document.querySelector('#gambar3');
let gambar4 = document.querySelector('#gambar4');
let gambar5 = document.querySelector('#gambar5');
let gambar6 = document.querySelector('#gambar6');
let gambar7 = document.querySelector('#gambar7');

gambar1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image/b1.jpg')";
});

gambar2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image/b2.jpg')";
});

gambar3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image/b3.jpg')";
});

gambar4.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image/b4.jpg')";
});

gambar5.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image/b5.jpg')";
});

gambar6.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image/b6.jpg')";
});

gambar7.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image/b7.jpg)";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 625px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide {
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: .2;
}

.slick-active {
  opacity: .5;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}

.center .slick-center h3 {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.08);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
  -o-transform: scale(1.08);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
  color: #e67e22;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.center h3 {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hidden1 {
  display: none;
}

.hidden2 {
  display: none;
}

.hidden3 {
  display: none;
}

.hidden4 {
  display: none;
}

.hidden5 {
  display: none;
}

.hidden6 {
  display: none;
}
```

````html
```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tes.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css">

<img src="image/b1.jpg" style="z-index: -1;">
<section class="background center slider variable-width variable-height ">
  <div id="gambar1" class="text-center sg-feature ">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/eat.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
    </br>
    <div id="newpost" class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gambar2" class="text-center sg-feature">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/grab.png " style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h3>Grab</h3>
    </br>
    <div id="newpost1" class="hidden  sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gambar3" class="text-center sg-feature">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/experience.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h3>Experience</h3>
    </br>
    <div id="newpost2" class="hidden  sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gambar4" class="text-center sg-feature">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/Secret sale.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h3>Secret Sale</h3>
    </br>
    <div id="newpost3" class="hidden  sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gambar5" class="text-center sg-feature ">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/sale.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h3>Hashtag Sale</h3>
    </br>
    <div id="newpost4" class="hidden  sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gambar6" class="text-center sg-feature ">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/loyalty.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h3>Loyalty</h3>
    </br>
    <div id="newpost5" class="hidden  sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gambar7" class="text-center sg-feature">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/auction.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h3>Auction</h3>
    </br>
    <div id="newpost6" class="hidden  sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the `#gambarN` elements are dynamically loaded by the Slick library. Therefore attaching an event handler to them when the page loads means that event handler is destroyed.

To fix this issue you can bind your logic which updates the background image to both the `init` and `afterChange` events. As the names imply, the former runs when the slider is initialised an the latter runs when the slide is changed. Within this event single handler you can read the URL of the image to set as the background from a `data` attribute in the HTML of the slide.

Also note that using incremental `id` attributes, such as `#gambarN` or `#newpostN` is an anti-pattern which leads to more complex code than necessary. Use common classes, as in the example below.

```js
let $slidesDescriptions = $('.sg-feature-desc');
let slickHandler = (e, slick) => {
  $slidesDescriptions.addClass('hidden');

  let $slide = $('.sg-feature').eq(slick.currentSlide);
  $slide.find('.sg-feature-desc').removeClass('hidden');
  $('body').css('background-image', `url('${$slide.data('bg')}')`);
}


let $slider = $('.center').on('init afterChange', slickHandler);
$slider.slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 6,
  speed: 300,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  variableHeight: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: false,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
      arrows: false,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '40px',
      slidesToShow: 3
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      arrows: false,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '40px',
      slidesToShow: 1
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 625px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide {
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: .2;
}

.slick-active {
  opacity: .5;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}

.center .slick-center h3 {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.08);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
  -o-transform: scale(1.08);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
  color: #e67e22;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.center h3 {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.sg-feature img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css">

<section class="background center slider variable-width variable-height ">
  <div class="text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/cqAklTF.jpeg">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/eat.png" />
    <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/epMSRQH.png">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/grab.png" />
    <h3>Grab</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="hidden sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/qZImY9j.jpeg">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/experience.png" />
    <h3>Experience</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="hidden sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/cqAklTF.jpeg">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/Secret sale.png" />
    <h3>Secret Sale</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="hidden sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/epMSRQH.png">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/sale.png" />
    <h3>Hashtag Sale</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="hidden sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/qZImY9j.jpeg">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/loyalty.png" />
    <h3>Loyalty</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="hidden sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/epMSRQH.png">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="image/auction.png" />
    <h3>Auction</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="hidden sg-feature-desc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js" ="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i want a background image when i open this page for the first time. I've tried several ways to insert an image for the background, but the icon goes down instead of behind it and I have a new problem when I click on another icon, the background image is not replaced. How do I fix it?

Comment: @BimoBaskoro apologies - I misunderstood your issue. I've updated my answer for you with a more appropriate solution.

Comment: hmmm, I have changed the code in my question and added a picture and what I want, maybe you can understand what I want.. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry - I managed to break the logic in my previous edit - it should be working now

Comment: its okay,but now the text that appears when I click the icon doesn't appear, how can I fix it?

Comment: thanks for the help, the code is working, have a nice day :)

Comment: Sorry to bother, I have another question, how do I make the slider position vertical?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. Googling 'make slick slider vertical' seems to have several solutions for this, though.